# building a matrix for currency conversion

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Got an assignment question that has me a little bit stumped

Task seems fairly simple, to write a function that takes a nested list of currencies and their conversion rates as parameters. Create a matrix with values for how much 10-100(in increments of 10) will get.

I've got this code here:

```
def Extract(cur):
    return [item[1] for item in cur]


def makeTable(cur):
    tlist = (Extract(cur))
    tlist.insert(0,1)
    print(tlist)
    for x in range(10,110,10):
        tbe = [(item[1]*x) for item in cur]
        print(tbe)
```

The issue I'm having here is that each sublist also needs the amount getting exchanged (10,20,30,40,etc). 
I'm really stumped on how to do this. 
I've also tried creating a new list of conversion rates from the old one, and inserting 1 at the start and just multiplying the lists but that didn't help much either

EDIT: I've attached an image of example [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT77a.png):

```
currencies = [['AUD', 0.96],['USD', 0.75],['Euro', 0.67],['GBP', 0.496]]
```

Comment: can you add an example and expected output

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by `tlist = (Extract(cur))`. It does not create a `tuple` with length 1 as you would expect. You need to do: `tlist = (Extract(cur),)`.

Comment: edited it with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def make_table(arr):
    items = [1] + [lst[1] for lst in arr]
    data = [[item * i for item in items] for i in range(10, 101, 10)]
    print(data)
make_table(currencies)
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 9.6, 7.5, 6.7, 4.96]
[20, 19.2, 15.0, 13.4, 9.92]
[30, 28.799999999999997, 22.5, 20.1, 14.879999999999999]
[40, 38.4, 30.0, 26.8, 19.84]
[50, 48.0, 37.5, 33.5, 24.8]
[60, 57.599999999999994, 45.0, 40.2, 29.759999999999998]
[70, 67.2, 52.5, 46.900000000000006, 34.72]
[80, 76.8, 60.0, 53.6, 39.68]
[90, 86.39999999999999, 67.5, 60.300000000000004, 44.64]
[100, 96.0, 75.0, 67.0, 49.6]]
```

Comment: @Komatiruju Thank you so much! That did the trick! Honestly can't thank you enough I was up till 5am fixated on this and couldn't get it!